# Need catch and parse json response by flash app in browser

Tags: javascript, java, jquery

I have one flash app. I'm running it in browser
Need catch and parse json response.

I have see 2 solution:

1. Catch response when it comming to browser
2. Wrote flash container on java or js, run app and parse response

Can you help me with best solution?

Comment: 1. You'll have to be more clear. Where is the response coming from? Are you sending a request that the Flash app is receiving and responding to? 2. Why are you using Flash? It's outdated and generally considered a security risk that most browsers will disable by default these days. Is there a better way to do what you want?

Comment: The flash app is game. When happening game event, app get response as json format. I need parse this response automatically